# Использование атрибутов

Tags: java, android

Как я могу использовать данный атрибут для другой вьюшки?

```
<declare-styleable name="pincodeView">
    <attr name="closeOnStart" format="boolean" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: если ваша View не наследник View, реализующей этот атрибут в своем коде, и сама не реализует его, то никак

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен что правильно понял Ваш вопрос, но моежете попробовать так

```
app:closeOnStart="false"
```